# Json Deserialization

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

EDIT 2: Apparently Apex has no idea what escaping character is... after I removed manually all `'\'` from that JSON, it worked.

I know this question was asked tens of times, but so far nothing works for me. I have a simple JSON from external application like this one:

> "[{\"Birthdate\":\"2004-11-11\",\"City1\":\"city1\",\"City2\":\"city22\",\"Country1\":\"bg\",\"Country2\":\"BG2\",\"Description\":\"a random desc\",\"Email\":\"jjrefjerf@efe.bg\",\"Fax\":\"32424234242\",\"FirstName\":\"fir333stname\",\"HomePhone\":\"82937423\",\"LastName\":\"rggrdgr\",\"Phone\":\"4234234242\",\"PostalCode\":\"34233\",\"PostalCode2\":\"231\",\"State1\":\"gkrdg\",\"State2\":\"state2\",\"Title\":\"a very frustrated SF user\",\"MailingStreet\":\"fsdfsdfs\",\"OtherStreet\":\"fdjsnfkjsd\"},{\"Birthdate\":\"2004-11-11\",\"City1\":\"city1\",\"City2\":\"city22\",\"Country1\":\"bg\",\"Country2\":\"BG2\",\"Description\":\"a random desc\",\"Email\":\"jjrefjerf@efe.bg\",\"Fax\":\"32424234242\",\"FirstName\":\"firs444tname\",\"HomePhone\":\"82937423\",\"LastName\":\"rggrdgr\",\"Phone\":\"4234234242\",\"PostalCode\":\"34233\",\"PostalCode2\":\"231\",\"State1\":\"gkrdg\",\"State2\":\"state2\",\"Title\":\"a very frustrated SF user\",\"MailingStreet\":\"fsdfsdfs\",\"OtherStreet\":\"fdjsnfkjsd\"},{\"Birthdate\":\"2004-11-11\",\"City1\":\"city1\",\"City2\":\"city22\",\"Country1\":\"bg\",\"Country2\":\"BG2\",\"Description\":\"a random desc\",\"Email\":\"jjrefjerf@efe.bg\",\"Fax\":\"32424234242\",\"FirstName\":\"firstn555ame\",\"HomePhone\":\"82937423\",\"LastName\":\"rggrdgr\",\"Phone\":\"4234234242\",\"PostalCode\":\"34233\",\"PostalCode2\":\"231\",\"State1\":\"gkrdg\",\"State2\":\"state2\",\"Title\":\"a very frustrated SF user\",\"MailingStreet\":\"fsdfsdfs\",\"OtherStreet\":\"fdjsnfkjsd\"}]"`

And i am trying to deserialize it using: `List<JSON2Apex> obj = System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<JSON2Apex>.class);` and my Json2Apex class look like this:

```
public class JSON2Apex {
    public String Birthdate;
    public String City1;
    public String City2;
    public String Country1;
    public String Country2;
    public String Description;
    public String Email;
    public String Fax;
    public String FirstName;
    public String HomePhone;
    public String LastName;
    public String Phone;
    public String PostalCode;
    public String PostalCode2;
    public String State1;
    public String State2;
    public String Title;
    public String MailingStreet;
    public String OtherStreet;
}
```

Is is possible for the error to comes from this string coming from C# service and therefore being put inside "" quotes, instead of single one ''? And if so, how can I change that because splitting it to chars and remaking it with '' instead doesn't work.

```
String source = res.getBody();
    String[] chars = source.split('');
    String newJson = '';
    for (Integer i = 1; i<chars.size();i++) {
        newJson = newJson + chars[i];
    }
```

The information there must be added to Contacts standard object, but I can't even extract it from that JSON.

P.S. - suggested answer didnt work.

Comment: according to the error message, I would assume that you will need to loop over your list to fill in the map

Comment: The data you have doesn't look like a map - try creating a map with the element type you are looking for, and serialize it, then compare it to the json you currently have.

Comment: You have totally changed your initial question, making my answer as invalid, better post your initial question here, close it and raise a new question, otherwise members will get confused why did they voted my answer which was acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

> Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map

So it is expecting a `List` which you are typecasting to a `Map` that's the issue. The thing that makes it a `List` is the fact that the JSON String starts with `[` and ends with `]`. Those delimiters are used to indicate a `List` (or Array if you prefer) in JSON.

I think you need to `deserialize` as below:

```
String str = response.getBody();

List<Contact> lstContact = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(str, List<Contact>.class);
```